# Enviar y Recibir Array en java con Sockets

Tags: java, socket

Estoy intentando hacer un Login, el cual al iniciar sesión un usuario, el cual(Login.java) enviara  el nombre a mi Socketserver.java este lo colocara en un arraylist y después enviara a los demás usuario el nombre del que se logeo(Menu.java), igualmente este podrá ver el nombre del los otros usuarios.

**El problema es que al logearse el "usuario1" vera su nombre, pero al logearse el "usuario 2" vera el nombre del "usuario"1" y de el mismo, mientras que el "Usuario1" solo vera su nombre y no el del "Usuario2".**

Aquí los fragmentos de código mas importantes
Codigo:

Login.java:

```
btnlogin.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            if(tUsuario.getText().length()>0 ){
                try{
                    socket = new Socket("localhost",3000);
                    netOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    String datos = "-"+tUsuario.getText();
                    localUser = tUsuario.getText();
                    netOut.writeUTF(datos); 
                    Menu p = new Menu(socket,primaryStage);
                    throw new IOException("Error");
                }catch(IOException ioe){
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                    

                }
            }
            
        } 
    });
```

Básicamente al colocar el nombre de usuario y dar clic al botón este abrirá otra ventana para desplegar el Menú.

SocketServer:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;


 public class SocketServer {


private static Vector<Socket> vSocket = new Vector<Socket>();
private static Vector<String> vectorUser = new Vector<>();
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        ServerSocket nwSocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
        while (true){
            Socket socket = nwSocket.accept();
            vSocket.add(socket);
            HiloMenu hMenu= new HiloMenu(socket, vSocket,vectorUser);
            Thread hilo = new Thread(hMenu);
            hilo.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Entonce crea un hilo para que puedan entrar mas usuarios y donde se guardan los datos, seria como el ClientSocket

HiloMenu:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;//DataInpout...
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;


public class HiloMenu implements Runnable {
private Socket socket;
private Vector<Socket> vSocket;
private Vector<String> vectorUser;
public HiloPrincipal(Socket socket, Vector<Socket>vSocket, Vector<String>vectorUser){
    this.socket = socket;
    this.vSocket = vSocket;
    this.vectorUser = vectorUser;
}
public void run(){
    try {
        String res="";
        
        while(true){
           
            DataInputStream netint = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String msg = netint.readUTF();
            StringTokenizer status = new StringTokenizer(msg,"-");
            
            if(status.countTokens()==1){
                System.out.println("Inicio sesion");
                
                res +=status.nextToken();
                vectorUser.addElement(res);


            }if(status.countTokens()==0){
                System.out.println("Traer a los usuarios");
                envia();
            }
            if(status.countTokens()>1){
                System.out.println("Cerrar sesion");
                String user = status.nextToken();
                
                if(vectorUser.size()==1){//si solo hay un solo usuario logedo
                    System.out.println("El usuario: "+vectorUser.get(0)+" Se fue!" );
                    vectorUser.remove(0);
                }
                else{
                    for(int i=0;i<vectorUser.size();i++){//si hay mas usuarios logiados
                        if(vectorUser.get(i).equals(user)){
                            System.out.println("El usuario: "+vectorUser.get(i)+" Se fue!" );
                            vectorUser.remove(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("vector resultante: "+vectorUser );
                vSocket.remove(socket);
                envia();
                socket.close();
            }

            
        }
        //por cada peticion se crearan sockets distintos
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void envia(){
    
    for(Socket socCliente: vSocket){
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream =new ObjectOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println(socCliente);
            outputStream.writeObject(vectorUser);
            
            
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("No se puede enviar los datos!");
            
        }
    }
}
```

}

Entonces conforme añadiendo los elementos, enviara mediante el ObjectInputStream a Menu.java

Menu.java

```
private void conectados(){

    Thread hilo = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            try{
    

                ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                Vector<String> myList = null;
                try{
                    
                    while(true){
                        

                        Object object = inputStream.readObject();
                        myList = (Vector<String>) object;
                        System.out.println("Mi lista: "+ myList);
                    }

                }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
                    System.out.println(ex.toString());
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }       
                
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.println("Se perdio la conexión");
                return;

            }
                
        }
    });
    hilo.start();

}
```

Para no colocar tanto código, en Menu.java lo que hace es recibir esos datos en el método conectados, para después escribirlos en un TextField, de momento los imprime.

Comment: @Alfabravo esta en negritas mi problema, que en si cuando se logea un usuario y otro se logea al primer usuario no le aparece el nombre del segundo usuario

Comment: Uuuuh mala mía, ofrezco disculpas! :)

Comment: @Alfabravo no te preocupes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucione simplemente enviando el Array o Vector  como una cadena de String

HiloMenu.java:

```
private void envia(){

    for(Socket socCliente: vSocket){
        try {

            DataOutputStream netOut = new DataOutputStream(socCliente.getOutputStream());
            String convertir;
            convertir =vectorUser.toString()
            
            netOut.writeUTF(convertir);
            
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("No se puede enviar los datos!");
            
        }
    }
}
```

En Menú.java cambie el ObjetcInputStream por DataInputStream, a la cadena de texto le quite los corchetes para que los remplace por espacios y despues myList lo que hace es quitar las coma para a,adirlos como un Array.

```
   DataInputStream netIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
   String texto = netIn.readUTF();
   String quita = texto.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
   myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str3.split(",")));
```